# How can I reset a page without resetting the router stack?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I need to reset a page when I go to it. But I don't want to reset the router stack so that I can still use `pop()` to go to the previous page.

I have tried with `Actions.pageName({type: ''})`:

`replace` But it resets the router stack.

`reset`   Also resets router stack.

`refresh` Doesn't even load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Actions.pop({refresh: {...propsToSetOnPreviousScene}})`

Comment: It would be good if you could add some explanation to the code as well.